# Continuity domain for momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space

I know this is essentially a mathematic question, but I received no answer on math SE. Moreover it has a direct application in physics, so I thought to ask this here too.

The momentum operator in one dimension in quantum mechanics is $P=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ (with $\hbar=1$). Consider it as an operator on $L_2(0,2\pi)$, the space of square-integrable functions on $(0,2\pi)$. It isn't continuous in fact if I consider the sequence
$$
g_n(x)=\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
$$
it's a Cauchy sequence but $\{Pg_n\}_n$ does not converge.

I am searching a domain where $P$ is a continuous functional. My professor gave me the example 
$$D_P=\{\varphi \in L_2(0,2\pi):\varphi(0)=\varphi(2\pi) \}$$
but I'm not convinced because if I consider the function $\psi$

\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   -\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\sqrt{\pi},\hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq x<\pi\\\sqrt{x-\pi},\hspace{0.5cm} \pi\leq x \leq 2\pi
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
it belongs to $D_P$, but if I apply $P$ on it I obtain

\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   \frac{i}{\sqrt{\pi}},\hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq x<\pi\\ -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{x-\pi}},\hspace{0.5cm} \pi\leq x \leq 2\pi
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
that is not square-integrable on $(0,2\pi)$.

[image]

Am I wrong? If not, which is a correct continuity domain for $P$?

Comment: Cross-posted form http://math.stackexchange.com/q/660630/11127

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, the answer to this technical question needs some mathematical technology.

The space you are looking for is $H^1(\mathbb R)$, the first **Sobolev Hilbert space**. It is made of the functions in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ admitting **the weak first derivative** represented by a $L^2$ function in turn.

$H^1(\mathbb R)$ is a complex Hilbert space if equipped with the scalar product: $$\langle \psi| \phi \rangle := \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\psi}(x) \phi(x) dx + \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\frac{d\psi}{dx}} \frac{d\phi}{dx} dx\qquad (1)$$ where $d/dx$ denotes the **weak derivative** (see below).

Equivalently, $H^1(\mathbb R)$ can be defined as the space of $L^2$ functions $\psi(x)$ whose Fourier (-Plancherel) transform $\hat{\psi}(k)$ admit finite $L^2$ norm with respect to the measure $(1+ k^2) ~ dk$ instead of the simpler $dk$.

Indeed it holds, where the scalar product is the same as in (1):
$$\langle \psi| \phi \rangle := \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\hat{\psi}}(k) \hat{\phi}(k)(1+ k^2)  dk \qquad (2)\:.$$

Obviously it also holds: $H^1(\mathbb R)\subset L^2(\mathbb R, dx)$

Sticking to work in the physically sensible Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R, dx)$ for QM, it turns out that  $H^1(\mathbb R)$ is the natural domain where the **momentum operator** is **self-adjoint** (not only Hermitian or symmetric). However, in that Hilbert space, the momentum operator, **whose correct definition is**:

$$P = -i \frac{d}{dx}\quad \mbox{in weak sense, and with domain $D(P)= H^1(\mathbb R)$}$$

is **always** unbounded, i.e. discontinuous.

So, to see $P$ as a bounded (i.e. continuous) operator it is not enough to restrict it to an appropriate domain, **but you also have  to change the topology (norm) of the domain**, passing from that of the simple $L^2$ to that of $H^1(\mathbb R)$. The topology in the co-domain remains that of $L^2$.

**NOTE 1**. A (measurable) function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is said to admit **weak derivative** $\frac{df}{dx}=g$, where $g$ is another (measurable) function, if, for every $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ of class $C^\infty$ and compactly supported, one has:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \frac{dh}{dx} dx = - \int_{\mathbb R} g(x) h(x) dx \:.$$
For instance $f(x)= |x|$ does not admit derivative at $x=0$ however admits weak derivative given by $\mbox{sgn}(x)$. The **Dirichlet function**
$d(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational $d(x)= 0$ if $x$ is not rational does not admit a derivative anywhere, but it admits weak derivative given by the zero function.

**NOTE 2**. If dealing with the particle in $[0,2\pi]$ the situation is analogous. The self-adjointness domain of $P$ is $H^1((0,2\pi))$ and $P$ is defined as before. The only change is that passing in Fourier rep. one has to use Fourier series instead of Fourier transform.  In this case the $H^1((0,2\pi))$ scalar product becomes:
$$\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \overline{\psi_n} \phi_n (1+ n^2)\:.$$
In the Hilbert space $H^1((0,2\pi))$ as domain and  with values in $L^2$, $P$ is continuous, otherwise, it is unbounded as usual.

What it is true in the statement of your professor, is that the set of $C^1$ functions on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)= f(2\pi)$ is included in $H^1((0,2\pi))$.

Comment: I did not think these so technical issues were so popular...

Comment: Thank you very much! I miss some math here but I think I understood. This is really useful and interesting to me!

Comment: I am puzzled. Is the last H^1 supposedly the same as the first mentioned one? Then I think this cant be true. A bounded operator has to have a bounded spectrum. (With periodic boundary condition I assume point spectrum, aka the Eigenvalues have to be bounded). But Eigenvalues dont change if you change the scalar product! So changing a scalar product alone can never make an operator bounded (while keeping the self-adjoint property). Could you elaborate?

Comment: What I wrote is that $P: H^1 \to L^2$ (not $H^1$) is bounded. This is not an operator defined  over  a *unique* Hilbert space so you cannot apply the standard results of spectral theory.

Comment: Indeed it was not clear in my answer, I will improve it.