# Physical meaning of the domain of a quantum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics

It's generally interesting to ask what's the physical interpretation of the various mathematical entities one employs in physics.

When doing quantum mechanics one often leaves aside all the “functional analytic” complications related to the unboundedness of the operator, the domain of the adjoint etc, and one works “as if” the Hilbert space is finite dimensional. I guess that the excuse could be that these things are unimportant when in comes to the actual physics? In fact, I am not aware of examples in which these questions are physically important.

However, these are all difficulties that arise when the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional, and I have the intuition that the infinite dimensionality is somehow physically important. For example, two operators $Q, \, P$ with $[Q, \, P] = i\hbar$ can't both be bounded, and thus one is forced to work in infinite dimensions.

**Question**: Are there examples that show that mathematical subtleties such as the infinite dimensionality and the choice of the domain of an operator are physically significant?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean with "physically significant", because after all you are discussing mathematics.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143055/interpreting-some-domain-issues-of-potential-momentum-operators)

Comment: I agree that I was probably too vague. I guess what I'm really asking is: is there some good reason not to ignore altogether this kind of issue? Or something along these lines.

Comment: Yes sure! You gave one example yourself. There are many examples in QM where one gets absurd results by performing not well defined operations (say, e.g. taking the trace over the CCR). To be mathematically rigorous is sometimes required to make, well, precise statements. As so often in physics, math can "guide" us the way. But as you already said in your post, in QM these things are often glossed over, because for a large part of undergrad and even grad QM they do not matter much in order to solve some model systems etc.

Comment: You get issues as soon as you introduce point masses in Newtonian mechanics. But it’s a sloppiness that’s necessary to get ahead.